# How do I get css links to resolve correctly when adding a PathInfo value?

Tags: asp.net, css, url, pathinfo

I have an asp.net 3.5 app. when I try to add a value to the url to be picked up in `Request.PathInfo`, i lose anything linked in `head` because the locations are resolved as relative paths.

master page looks like this:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='~/App_Themes/main/style.css' type="text/css"  />
</head>
```

and renders like this

```
<head id="ctl00_ctl00_Head1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../App_Themes/main/style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

and so when i go to

```
http://localhost:5000/project/folder/edit.aspx/555
```

the browser is looking for the stylesheet at

```
http://localhost:5000/project/folder/App_Themes/main/style.css
```

instead of

```
http://localhost:5000/project/App_Themes/main/style.css
```

is it automatic behavior to resolve with a relative path? can I change it? is this something the previous developer is doing that i haven't found?

--- edit  ---

i took the suggestion below and added a `base` element like so

```
<base id="ctl00_ctl00_baseElement" href="http://localhost:5000/project/"></base>
```

but my links still don't work because asp.net is insistent on rendering the urls as relative paths unless the `href` starts with `/`, but in both cases i end up one level too high now.

```
http://localhost:5000/App_Themes/main/style.css
```

Comment: So "project" would change depending on your project?

Comment: @luke yeah, that's how the asp.net dev server works. `localhost:port/project name/stuff`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when the `head` element is defined as a server control, `link` elements within are automatically parsed and resolved by the server. So the solution is to have the head element as a standard html control only or possibly manually add your `link` elements. I bailed on the `PathInfo` idea I was pursuing so I didn't get that far.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<base href="http://yourdomain.com">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/App_Themes/main/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this issue, adding an html 'base' tag,
Using method: Page.ResolveUrl("~") to resolve the base url of the site.
Works well on both localhost and server:

```
    <base href="<%=ResolveUrl("~")%>" />
```